# SharePoint 2010: blocking the screen on load

Tags: javascript, ajax

We are hosting some SP2010 sites and some of our users are a little quick on the trigger and try to click on an order before the page is done loading, inadvertantly approving it by mistake. Repeated attempts to scold them have failed and so I would like to find out if there is an approved or correct way to insitutue something like a full screen pre-loader, something like a [blockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)? In ASP.NET for example, you can just hook to the AJAX toolkit, and I'm sure there is something similar in SharePoint, but if there is a cleaner way, I would like to know about it.

ADD: What I would like to do is catch the event. So in ASP.NET you could do something like this:

```
var pmgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

pmgr.add_beginRequest(foo());
```

... and than you could catch the event. I'm trying to accomplish the same thing but in SharePoint.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, I can build an Event Receiver and override each event so that they perform some JavaScript method Pre-Event and Post-Event. This may solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is the same as ASP.NET. You can just tap into ScriptResource.axd where PageRequestManager exists.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just leave the Approve button "disconnected" by default and then wire it up in $(document).ready()?

Comment: It's not just the Approve button that i'm worried about. I would want the page blocked every time an AJAX request occurs (for example).